# Need to customize the log message

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to customize the log message so that i can have information like:

- thread id
- user name (logged in user)
- Session id
- class name
- method name
- error/log message

The reason for customizing the log is that the application is `multi-threaded` and we need some handle to trace logs related to particular `user/thread.`

I am a bit new to logging framework and have always used simple `log4j` implementation. So, please suggest best way to incorporate this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mapped Diagnostic Context for your use cases. You can store/set all your information in a map like structure provided by MDC. The MDC structure is internally attached to the executing thread in the same way a ThreadLocal variable would be. Moreover MDC is compatible with Log4j,Log4j2 and Slf4j. 
For usage you can refer this link : http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback